# What is this percentage in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: ide, sublimetext3

Every so often, I'll open up Sublime Text and my CPU will start going crazy, temperature goes up, and there is this percentage at the bottom right of Sublime Text that slowly updates. I've tried Googling for an answer but to no avail. Does anyone know what the percentage represents? Is it indexing my files or something? How can I update the settings for this? [image: Screenshot of Sublime Text 3 Percentage]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the percentage is the indexing status. This can be viewed in more detail from the `Help menu -> Indexing Status...`. This menu item was added in build 3125.

There are various settings to control indexing, all of which have to go in your User preferences - they currently don't work in Project settings.
Related issues:

- https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1277
- https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1338

---

```
// File indexing parses all files in the side bar, and builds an index of
// their symbols. This is required for Goto Definition to work.
"index_files": true,

// Set the number threads to use for indexing. A value of 0 will make
// Sublime Text guess based on the number of cores. Use the index_files
// setting to disable all workers.
"index_workers": 0,

// index_exclude_patterns indicate which files won't be indexed.
"index_exclude_patterns": ["*.log"],

// These files will still show up in the side bar, but won't be included in
// Goto Anything or Find in Files
"binary_file_patterns": ["*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.ttf", "*.tga", "*.dds", "*.ico", "*.eot", "*.pdf", "*.swf", "*.jar", "*.zip"],
```

---

As the `node_modules` folder tends to be massive, this is probably the cause of your indexing taking a while and using lots of system resources. However, at the moment, [`index_exclude_patterns` only applies to file names](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/solved-high-cpu-usage-in-beta-3124/23060/19), so if you want to prevent indexing of the `node_modules` folder, you will need to add it to `binary_file_patterns`, which, despite it's name, also operates on folders.

Example:

```
"binary_file_patterns": ["node_modules/", "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.ttf", "*.tga", "*.dds", "*.ico", "*.eot", "*.pdf", "*.swf", "*.jar", "*.zip"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer!

Comment: I wish I could upvote multiple times for the `binary_file_patterns` tidbit.  I couldn't figure out why `index_exclude_patterns` wasn't working.